# Dealing with Euclidean distance and dimension independence

Tags: distance-functions, euclidean

I'm not very well informed in terms of distance measures.

What sort of distance measure would I use if I know that the various dimensions are not independent of each other? Because I think that euclidean distance assumes that the dimensions are independent.

Comment: `Because I think that euclidean distance assumes that the dimensions are independent` Why do you think so?

Comment: We're just subtracting based on corresponding dimension. There is no interaction. Am I incorrect?